# Grouping up certain lists of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to group up many lists of lists  which is very long, and can be found here:
Essentially want I am trying to do is group

```
[[1,1]] 
[[1,2]] 
[[2,1]] 
[[2,2]]
```

etc.

I wrote a for loop looks something like this, but doesn't really work.

```
For[i = 1, i <= 20, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 2, i++,
  newyyyy = StringJoin[y[[i, j]]]
  ]
 ]
```

I would appreciate any help. Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your list is called `alist`, the `result` would contain 20 lists with 80 concatenated strings each:

```
result = MapThread[StringJoin, #] & /@ alist;
Dimensions@result
```

> {20, 80}

Comment: Thanks! kind sir